# How to return a double or string for a method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method:

```
public static double c(string val)
{
    return Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(val), 4);
}
```

Where I pass in a string, and if its a double, I want to round then return a double, but if its a string, I want to return a string as is.  All of the parameters that I pass in will be strings to start, how do i determine if its a string or double, and how do i rewrite the methoed to have the return type flexible enough to return either?

Ideally, I would like to use type variant like in vba, but i dont think there is an analog in c#.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How would it be used? Your caller will expect a single return type - either double or string, not both.

Comment: @greg You should accept an answer if you believe this has been answered.

Answer (score 4):

The following will try to parse the `double`. If returns `true` it will put the double in the output variable `output`; else return `false` means `val` isn't a double and you should use the `string val` instead.

```
public static bool c(string val, out double output)
{
    if (double.TryParse(val, out output))
    {
        output = Math.Round(output, 4);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        output = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
string val = "123.45678";
double output;
if ( c(val, out output) )
{
    // use double output
}
else
{
    // val isn't a double, just use val directly
}
```

Comment: @greg, if you consider my answer the best solution to your problem, please accept this as the solution by clicking the tick next to this post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`typeof()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and set your parameter of the function to `object`. Then you can pass everything to the function and can check the type with [`typeof()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Maybe you can also think of [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)...

Comment: With generics the caller needs to know what type will be returned. Here its vice versa, the method knows what type it will return after it checked if the string is numeric. The caller only knows it when it comes back.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, you're true, but I wanted to mention him the generics. Thats why I'm added it as a comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do such a thing, but how about with dynamic type...

```
    public dynamic func(string s)
    {
        double d = 0;
        if (double.TryParse(s, out d))
            return Math.Round(d, 4);
        return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 4 you can use

```
public static string c(string val)
    {
        Double result;
        if (Double.TryParse(val, out result))
            return Math.Round(result, 4).ToString();
        else
            return val;
    }
```

If you are not using .Net 4

```
public static string c(string val)
    {
        try
        {
            Double result = Convert.ToDouble(val);
            return Math.Round(result, 4).ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return val;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is .net 4 specific about your first method? TrParse was added in framework 2.0.  In your second block, you should be catching FormatException and OverflowException, not base Exception.

Comment: Double.TryParse is not limited to .net 4.0... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I thought that TryParse was not added until 4.0.